# NullPointer Exception in Service.onStartCommand after APK being closed. How to deal with it?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, nullpointerexception

There is a service which has to process data from `Intent` in its `Handler`.
Snippet below:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mServiceHadler.sendMessage(msg);
    return  START_STICKY;
}
```

After invocation of Intent to start service and removing APK from overview screen in consequence one gets `NullPointerException` because of `null` `Intent` has came.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.intentservicetest01.ServiceExt@750547a with null: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4021)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1841)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7014)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:731)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:621)
```

Is there canonical clear (without adding conditional `null` check) way to deal with `null` `Intent`?

Will this callback method (`Service.onStartCommand`) survive if the service will be started in another process? Any suitable ideas are appreciated.

Comment: already answered ... also read documentation of START_STICKY

Comment: @Selvin thanks. START_REDELIVER_INTENT solve the problem. Will you post an answer to the post?

Comment: @walkmn `intent` is null exact. NullPinterException is all about it.

Comment: try to stop service in its override method `onTaskRemoved`

Comment: @vmarkeev overriding `onTaskRemoved` works gives the service an appropriate behaviour. Will you post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try stop your `service` like this

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    stopSelf();
}
```

or start it in this way

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // your code
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

Comment: please, update the answer with alternative solution of returning appropriate value from `Service.onStartCommand` (check [Selvin comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669156/nullpointer-exception-in-service-onstartcommand-after-apk-being-closed-how-to-d/33686712#comment-55111362) + my re-comment on it).

Answer (score 2):

I like to coding like this, use @Nullable Annotation.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand: " + intent.getCategories());
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

If intent is used but is not checked, there is a warning like this: 
[warning info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CThI.png)
then you may do it easyly.